# Parsing with multiple delimiters, in C

Tags: c, string, parsing, delimiter

In C, what is the best way to parse a string with multiple delimiters? Say I have a string `A,B,C*D` and want to store these values of A B C D. I'm not sure how to deal with the `*` elegantly, other than to store the last string `C*D` and then parse that separately with a `*` delimiter.

If it was just `A,B,C,*D` I'd use strtok() and ignore the first index of the `*D` to get just D, but there is no comma before the `*` so I don't know that `*` is coming.

Comment: the code could use strtok() with a list of delimiters in the string containing the delimiters.  I.E. if( NULL != (pResult = strtok( targetString, ",*" )))  and for successive tokens: if( NULL != strtok( NULL, ",*" )))  However, note that strtok() will not stop on each delimiter when successive delimiters with no intervening characters.  I.E. for ',*' will not stop on the '*'  Also, be sure the string is nul byte terminated

Comment: @user3629249, if it's not terminated, it's not _actually_ a string :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use *multiple* delimiters with `strtok`, the second argument is a C string with the *list* of delimiters in it, not just a single delimiter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char myStr[] = "A,B,C*D";

    char *pChr = strtok (myStr, ",*");
    while (pChr != NULL) {
        printf ("%s ", pChr);
        pChr = strtok (NULL, ",*");
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

The output of that code is:

```
A B C D
```

Comment: I can't understand your solution, if you think why I tell you : multiples delimiters is if you use three "strtok"  or more in a while .... your example not resolve this question.

Comment: @delive, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say. The answer delivers *exactly* what OP asked for. If you have a different question, you should ask it as a different question.